# Create an icon in memory with win32 in python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, icons

What's a good way to generate an icon in-memory in python? Right now I'm forced to use pygame to draw the icon, then I save it to disk as an .ico file, and then I load it from disk as an ICO resource...

Something like this:

```
    if os.path.isfile(self.icon):
        icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
        hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(hinst,
                                   self.icon,
                                   win32con.IMAGE_ICON,
                                   0,
                                   0,
                                   icon_flags)
```

...where self.icon is the filename of the icon I created.

Is there any way to do this in memory? EDIT: All I want to do is create an icon with a 2-digit number displayed on it (weather-taskbar style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/) for this.

```
from wx import EmptyIcon
icon = EmptyIcon()
icon.CopyFromBitmap(your_wxBitmap)
```

The [wxBitmap](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxbitmap.html#wxbitmap) can be generated in memory using [wxMemoryDC](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxmemorydc.html#wxmemorydc), look [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxdc.html) for operations you can do on a DC.

This icon can then be applied to a wxFrame (a window) or a wxTaskBarIcon using:

```
frame.SetIcon(icon)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a object that mimics the python file-object interface.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me and doesn't require wx.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

CreateIconFromResourceEx = windll.user32.CreateIconFromResourceEx
size_x, size_y = 32, 32
LR_DEFAULTCOLOR = 0

with open("my32x32.png", "rb") as f:
    png = f.read()
hicon = CreateIconFromResourceEx(png, len(png), 1, 0x30000, size_x, size_y, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR)
```